# How to install modules in app/code with composer in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, composer

How can I force composer to install modules in `app/code` instead of `vendor` directory in Magento 2?

I have few modules they strictly need to be install in `app/code`, but when I update them with composer, they install in `vendor` directory.

Answer (score 8):

I'm answering my own question, so it will be beneficial for someone else later,

To be able to install in a custom path, your module must support `composer/installers` so add it to your module's `require` section, eg:

```
"require": {
   "magento/magento-composer-installer": "*",
   "composer/installers": "~1.0"
}
```

and then give your module a custom path in `extra` section, where you want it to be installed. Eg:

```
"extra": {
   "installer-paths": {
      "app/code/Vendor/Module": ["vendor/module"]
   }
 }
```

and your module type must be `"type": "magento-library"` not `"type": "magento2-module"` (don't worry changing the type will not break anything, it'll still work like before)

so the complete json for the module will be like something this

```
{
    "name": "vendor/module",
    "description": "some description about your module",
    "require": {
        "magento/magento-composer-installer": "*",
        "composer/installers": "~1.0"
    },
    "type": "magento-library",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "extra": {
        "installer-paths": {
            "app/code/Vendor/Module": ["vendor/module"]
        }
    }
}
```

and just to be sure, add it to your main `composer.json`'s extra section too, this maybe optional but I have added it anyway.

```
"extra": {
   "magento-force": "override",
     "installer-paths": {
       "app/code/Vendor/Module": ["vendor/module"]
   }
 }
```

Then run `composer update`, so it will install your module in `app/code` or your given path.

Comment: not working on m2.2.2

Comment: Using this method on 2.2 E still adds the module to the vendor folder.

Answer (score 1):

instead of using composer you may extract file and paste it in to app/code/ create a folder structure like Vendorename/Modulename as in registration.php

Comment: No my current requirement is to use it with composer, anyway i figured it out if you use `"extra": {
        "map": [
            [
                "*",
                "Vendor\/Module_Name"
            ]
        ]
    }` it does add the module to `app/code` but it also in `vendor`