# When would you place a module in the app/code folder versus another location?

Tags: magento2, module, composer

> When would you place a module in the app/code folder versus another
>   location?

If I add new module in `app/code folder` with `composer.json` and another module in `vendor folder` using `composer`

> What will be the difference ?

- I am aware about that if module is in `vendor folder` then It can be
  updated  by composer.
- Does that same thing apply with the module which is in `app/code
  folder` ?
- When you update module which is in `app/code folder` using `composer`
  they install in vendor directory.

> So, What is the point of `Composer.json` in `app/code` folder Module ?

Comment: `composer.json` specifies the dependencies of your `custom module`.

Comment: files inside `vendor folder` are installed by the `composer` on the server. your `custom/module` will specify the dependencies in `composer.json` file using `require` key. That is, to make sure that composer will install `packages` your `custom module` has a dependencies.

Comment: also, `composer json` is where your put the metadata for you `custom module`. You will notice once you check from **Magento Module Setup**, your `custom module` will have the information filled in like a `vendor name` and `version` and etc taken from the `composer.json` file. Otherwise, it will display blank or unknown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you already pointed out, composer is a package management tool. Any external modules/packages which constitutes your Magento application will be managed by the composer and will be available under `vendor` directory, provided you have adopted the composer way of installation/ updating of your Magento instance. Magento core modules are also treated as external packages which constitute your Magento application.

`app/code` expects those Magento modules which are "unique" to your Magento application. Those jobs or customization which we cannot achieve by a third party/external modules has to be here. In most of the time, these modules are not installed or updated using composer. In most of the projects, your version system generally holds and manage your `app/code` folder only (There are other folder files we need to keep inside a versioning system, but none of them as relevant as modules inside `app/code`.

But it is a good practice to keep a `composer.json` file for those modules too. Reasons are many:

- Magento recommends it as a good practice.
- You can specify your module dependencies there. ex: php version, core module dependencies etc.
- If in case, if you want to make your module a general third-party extension, then it would be so easy.

If you need more details of composer.json files which are using in Magento, you can [follow this official documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/build/composer-integration.html) about the composer.json file.

Comment: Thanks @Rajeev for the explanation it clears a lot. +1

Answer (score 3):

Modules in **`vendor folder`** would update using **`composer`**

And all the **modules** in **`app/code`** would not be updated through **`composer`**

That's why when you need to **override** any module you add it in **app/code**

Comment: So, What is the point of Composer.json in app/code folder Module ?

Comment: You can update/install your module in app/code
By following this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/188429/how-to-install-modules-in-app-code-with-composer-in-magento-2/188431

Comment: By default it only updates vendor directory

Comment: Thanks @shaikh for the answer +1