# Magento 2: How to install custom module in app/code folder only using composer.json file?

Tags: magento2, module, installation, composer

I'm trying to install my custom module using `composer.json` file and after run 
`composer update` command my custom module installed successfully in magento2.

Actually I want to install my custom module in `app/code` directory using composer.json and I have found some solution from dedicated developers and add extra section in my composer.json as following:

```
"extra": {
    "map": [
        [
            "*",
            "Gotham/Customimgattr"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Using the above code snippet my module added in `app/code` folder but also added in `vendor` directory. So anyone knows how to install custom module in `app/code` folder only not in `vendor` using composer.json file? Thanks in advance. My composer.json file:-

```
{
    "name": "myproject/mymodule",
    "description": "Upload Db Schema",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
     "require": {
        "php": "7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0"
      },
      "type": "magento2-module",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "extra": {
        "map": [
            [
                "*",
                "Gotham/Customimgattr"
            ]
        ]
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to install in a custom path, your module must support composer/installers so add it to your module's require section, eg:

"require": {
"magento/magento-composer-installer": "*",
"composer/installers": "~1.0"
}
and then give your module a custom path in extra section, where you want it to be installed. Eg:

"extra": {
"installer-paths": {
"app/code/Vendor/Module": ["vendor/module"]
}
}
and your module type must be "type": "magento-library" not "type": "magento2-module" (don't worry changing the type will not break anything, it'll still work like before)

so the complete json for the module will be like something this

{
"name": "vendor/module",
"description": "some description about your module",
"require": {
"magento/magento-composer-installer": "*",
"composer/installers": "~1.0"
},
"type": "magento-library",
"version": "1.0.0",
"license": [
"OSL-3.0",
"AFL-3.0"
],
"extra": {
"installer-paths": {
"app/code/Vendor/Module": ["vendor/module"]
}
}
}
and just to be sure, add it to your main composer.json's extra section too, this maybe optional but I have added it anyway.

"extra": {
"magento-force": "override",
"installer-paths": {
"app/code/Vendor/Module": ["vendor/module"]
}
}
Then run composer update, so it will install your module in app/code or your given path.
I am referring form this answer
[How to install modules in app/code with composer in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/188429/how-to-install-modules-in-app-code-with-composer-in-magento-2)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

In your root `composer.json` file, under `repositories` add:

`"local-packages": {type": "path", url": "./app/code/*"}`

Then add your module under `app/code` and require it via composer.